# ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch

Tags: angular, primeng, mismatch

i'm new to angular ( using v.4 for now) and i'm working on a project for my studies and it's also my first time trying Primeng modules. 
I  tried to integrate the "datagrid" to my project and after i did "ng serve", i've got this error :

[enter image description here][1]

ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/test1/node_modules/primeng/components/common/api.d.ts,
found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/test1/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol App
Module in C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/test1/src/app/app.module.ts
    at Error (native)
    at syntaxError (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:
26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtool
s_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:212:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\test1\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin
.js:448:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Please can someone tell me what should i do ? i checked other similar questions but i didn't get what i'm supposed to do to solve this problem :x

Comment: what content in package.json?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "primeng": "^5.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"

Comment: Can you try one thing .. Actually here versions are mismatch..So create new project and maintain all versions..Here version of angular is 4 or primeng is 5

Comment: you mean i have to update angular to v.5 and to recreate my project ? , and excuse me i have one question : how is this related to the error saying that Metadata version mismatch for module [..] found version 4 and expected 3? ^^

Comment: aah i got it !! PrimeNG 5 does not work on Angular 4 due to AOT constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same error, the error is because of **version mismatch** with the dependencies, **i,e all the dependencies are not in the same version**, to solve this **update all the dependencies or downgrade all** to the common version, **update is the better options**,
this link helps to upgrade all the dependencies,
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/